# Lock up when running spiral knights

Tags: 12.04, wine

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 I installed steam through Windows 1.4 and that works fine. I also installed spiral knights through steam. Wine HQ says that it runs properly, but when I run it the screen goes black.

When I press the prt sc button it makes te camera sound and changing the volume buttons work, but the only way to get my screen back is to shut down with the power button.

Is there anyway to fix this problem and be able to play spiral knights?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed, and ran Spiral Knights to test your issue.

How I accomplished it:

- Install PlayOnLinux from the software center or [their website](http://www.playonlinux.com)
- In PlayOnLinux click `Install` -> `Games` -> `Steam`.
- Then go about installing spiral knights as you would in Windows.

If this still doesn't work then I would suggest trying unity 2d as the issue maybe due to a graphics card driver issue.